# How to design an frontend AJAX structure for a previous CRUD ORM in back end

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, crud

So basically i have a backend ORM class which can do all the CRUD methods already done.

I have a front end which needs to access the backend for these CRUD with the respective tables/views. But is there an easy way to perform front end task.

So, basically what i am asking is How to program a XML based ajax structure which lets me easily execute my CRUD methods in background. Any tutorials and helpful links are appreciated, including your answers :)

I am looking for a generic answer which can be extended to many types. *I want to reduce the code i write*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo provides a [data abstraction api](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data.html#dojox-data) to make it easy the connection with backend services with different formats (XML, Atom, JSON).

I have used the [REST-based JSON store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data/JsonRestStore.html). You only have to create the server-side CRUD operations. A tutorial is available here: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/13/restful-json-dojo-data/

Comment: I am more familiar with jquery than dojo. Is there anything for jquery?

Comment: JQuery is more focused on DOM manipulation, so server-side databinding is not in their core purpose. Maybe some plug-ins can provide it, but the advantadge of Dojo-ata is that it can be integrated with the widget system regardles of the data provider.